# How to let a bootstrap container use the remaining viewport space?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, blazor

I know there are a number of similar posts, but I am unable to apply them to my issue.

I have a table in the last row of a bootstrap grid:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Here are some other rows with dynamically varying sizes -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        <th>Size (byte)</th>
                        <th>Loaded</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var file in _filesToUpload)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@file.Name</td>
                            <td>@file.FileType</td>
                            <td>@file.FileSize</td>
                            <td>@file.Loaded.ToString()</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The corresponding `css` looks like this:

```
.table {
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0.941, 0, 0.5);
}

.table-responsive {
    height: 40rem;
    overflow: auto;
}

thead tr:nth-child(1) th {
    background-color: black;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

The whole thing is within a `.page` container and a `main` container (this is blazor default project setup):

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>

    <div class="main">
        <div class="top-row px-4 auth">
            <LoginDisplay />
        </div>

        <div class="content px-4">
            @Body <!-- here the code from above gets inserted -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And lastly I have the following `css` for the `page` and `main` class.

```
.page {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: transparent;
}


.main {
    flex: 1;
    background-image: url(../web/wallpaper.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top 0 right 0;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

What I would want to have is that the background is fixed in place and all content, that gets too big, gets a scrollbar. With the above code, this works fine as long as I'm in full-screen/ full HD mode. As soon as the browser gets resized, the table will 'stick out' of the bottom of the page (the whole page gets an additional scrollbar and one can scroll down below the background image).

The solution must be to use a dynamic height in the `table-responsive` class, but I'm unable to find the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Bootstrap utilites way:

Using a very basic layout to demonstrate:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<article class="flex-fill d-flex flex-column">
    @Body
</article>
```

`ScrollDiv.razor`

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column flex-fill overflow-auto @CssClasses">
    @ChildContent
</div>
```

`ScrollDiv.razor.cs`

```
public partial class ScrollDiv : ComponentBase
{
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string? CssClasses { get; set; }
}
```

`SomePage.razor`

```
...
<div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-stretch mh-100 vh-100 overflow-hidden">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column border-end " style="min-width: 220px;">
            <ScrollDiv>
                <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                    @foreach (var user in MessageService!.Users)
                    {
                        <ChatUserView User=@user OnClickCallback=@UserClicked />
                    }
                </div>
            </ScrollDiv>
...
```

Screen shot: [image]

Comment: Trying to unpack this... So ScrollDiv should probably go into a `Shared` folder, right?
I will test this out and report back, will take an hour or two. Thanks! :)

Comment: @RolandDeschain yes. The contents of the partial class `ScrollDiv.razor.cs` can be put in the `@code { }` block in the `ScrollDiv.razor` file if your wish. Im using the code behind approach here out of habbit. Keep the two files together...

Comment: Yeah, I usually do the same thing, just meant that the `ScrollDiv.razor` and `ScrollDiv.razor.cs` should probably be available in multiple places...therefore I would put it in a shared folder (as opposed to pages folder). Sorry for the confusion, I'm coming from WPF development, the whole web-project structure thing is still a bit new and confusing to me ^^

Comment: @RolandDeschain First think I do is create a "Views" folder and drag shared and pages into that. I then rename "Shared" to "Components" usually and then fix the "_imports.razor" to match. With Server-side you have you also change the root for the pages to be found.